# How do I update my state after deleting values in an array which was processed with join()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have an array called `selectedOption` that looks like this:

```
[
   "Fantasy",
    "Mystery",
    "Romance",
   "Scifi"
];
```

Using a multi-select input,

[image]

I can choose multiple options, (ie. Romance, Mystery). Then save these in a state called `query`

When I log `selectedOption` in the browser terminal and copy it, it looks like this

```
[
    [
        "Mystery",
        "Romance"
    ]
]
```

[image]

**Problem**

As mentioned, I need to get the string(s) and save them in `query`. Below is how I check if the array has stuff in it, and if it does, I use join() to get the string values and then I save that into 'query' (This data in `query` is used for a query search)

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState();

    //selecting an option

    const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
        const copy = [...selectedOption];
        copy.push(e);
        setSelectedOption(copy);

    //to zone in on what I need, I have to get the first array value.
        console.log(selectedOption[0]);

        //only perform join() if the array has stuff in it.

        if(!selectedOption.length){
        } else {
            let joinedArr = selectedOption[0].join(", ");

            //save the strings into my query state
            setQuery(joinedArr)
            console.log(query)
        }
    };
```

**Results**
Here is my query state, exactly what I want:
[image]

**Problem**
Everything kinda works to this point. The issue I have is that, when I delete 'Romance' for example, it's not reflected in my query state. Below is the code to remove one select option. How do I write this code so that when I delete an option, it's reflected in my query `state`, do I need to make it into an object again?

```
    const handleTypeRemove = (e) => {
        const copy = [...selectedOption];
        let index = copy.indexOf(e);
        copy.splice(index, 1);
        setSelectedOption(copy);
    };
```

When I delete something ie.
[image]

It does not delete it from `query`- here is the log fired up after calling `handleTypeRemove`
[image]

Your help is greatly appreciated, assume you are explaining to a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copied variable does not change the state, you'll have to also update the `query` with `setQuery`

```js
    const handleTypeRemove = (e) => {
        const copy = [...selectedOption];
        let index = copy.indexOf(e);
        copy.splice(index, 1);
        setSelectedOption(copy);
        setQuery(copy.join(', '));
    };
```

Instead of having two sets of logic doing the same thing, instead you can use [React useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Like so

```js
  const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
    const copy = [...selectedOption];
    copy.push(e);
    setSelectedOption(copy);
  };
  const handleTypeRemove = (e) => {
    const copy = [...selectedOption];
    const index = copy.indexOf(e);
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    setSelectedOption(copy);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedOption.length) {
    } else {
      const joinedArr = selectedOption[0].join(", ");

      //save the strings into my query state
      setQuery(joinedArr);
      console.log(query);
    }
    // this means this code inside this block runs everytime selectedOption changes
  }, [selectedOption]);
```